# Error when using FIELDS(STANDARD) in an Apex SOQL query : System.QueryException: No such column 'EffectiveDate' on entity 'Quote'

Tags: apex, soql

I recently implemented the new [`FIELDS(STANDARD)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fields.htm) functionality in Apex queries and I am using the following query now:

```
SELECT FIELDS(STANDARD), Custom1__c, ... , CustomN__c 
FROM Quote 
WHERE Id =: quoteId
```

However I'm getting the error `No such column 'EffectiveDate' on entity 'Quote'`. The odd thing is that it's obviously a Standard field being queried in but the field itself doesn't exist... Unless I'm missing something, I can't seem to find it anywhere. Is it a field from another API version or is it something else? As a reference I'm using API v.51.

Any help would be appreciated! Let me know if I can add more information as well to help clarify my issue.

**Edit:**

As per request of @sfdcfox, I'll try to create a Minimum Viable Reproduction of this scenario and edit my post if I can come up with one. In the meantime, here are a few more contextual points to help with troubleshooting:

The query technically has a few nested queries so it actually looks something like

```
SELECT FIELDS(STANDARD), 
       Custom_Field__c, 
      (SELECT FIELDS(STANDARD), 
              Custom_Field__c 
              FROM QuoteLineItems LIMIT 100), 
      (SELECT FIELDS(STANDARD), 
              Custom_Field__c 
              FROM ChildRecords__r LIMIT 100)
FROM Quote WHERE Id =: quoteId
```

This query is being ran inside a queued context (the very first action inside the queued context as well), and occurring after the creation of an `Opportunity` record.

Comment: Are you using a v52 scratch org, by chance?

Comment: @sfdcfox I'm in a full sandbox, but it's using v52.0, yes.

Comment: What are the versions of your main and test classes? I know historically there were problems when fields were queried in the wrong version, I suspect this may be a bug. I'm going to try and replicate this in a preview scratch org.

Comment: Both main and test class are v51.0.

Comment: Okay, so I can't replicate this in a 51 org or 52 org, using 51 api or 52 api, or even by way of setting the unit test to a lower api (e.g. 47), or by adding custom fields. I don't have any sandboxes I can use, so I'm pretty much stuck. Have you tried replicating in a 52 Scratch Org? Can you make a Minimum Viable Reproduction you can share with us? I'd be happy to take a look at it and engage with the appropriate people if I can get a repro.

Comment: Updated my post with some more contextual info. I'll look into making that MVR!

Comment: @sfdcfox I wasn't able to replicate this inside a scratch org either... Any other thoughts/ideas on how to go about either replicating this or even determining the issue?

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions without being able to log in to your org. I think your best bet would be Technical Support.

Comment: That edit is actually very enlightening, I think. Let me try that out.